# Error Screen Display Android 8.1 when Flip Portrait Rotation 180

Tags: android, screen, android-8.1-oreo

Why My Display like this? Flip Portrait Or Rotation 180 Mode, but Landscape position. This I running on Virtual Device by Android Studio Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10671973 with OS Image Oreo Android 8.1x86

[Error Screen][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHWbH.png